# Displaying rating star in Django

Tags: html, django, font-awesome

I am writing a small Django website and I want display rating stars but am a bit stuck.
In my html file, I am doing something like below

```
<div class="rating-star">
    <span>
        <i class="fas fa-star{% if review.rating == 0.5 %}-half-alt {% endif %}" aria-hidden="true"></i>

        <i class="fas fa-star{% if review.rating == 1.5 %}-half-alt {% endif %}" aria-hidden="true"></i>

        <i class="fas fa-star{% if review.rating == 2.5 %}-half-alt {% endif %}" aria-hidden="true"></i>

        <i class="fas fa-star{% if review.rating == 3.5 %}-half-alt {% endif %}" aria-hidden="true"></i>

        <i class="fas fa-star{% if review.rating == 4.5 %}-half-alt {% endif %}" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </span>
</div>
```

In each `<i>` tag, I also want use `elif` to display `far fa-star`.
Let me show an example using fontawesome v4.7. In fontawesome v4.7, it looks like below and I want to achieve the same thing with fontawesome v5.13 but I don't know to

```
<span>
    <i class="fa fa-star{% if review.rating == 0.5 %}-half-o{% elif review.rating < 1 %}-o {% endif %}" aria-hidden="true"></i>

    <i class="fa fa-star{% if review.rating == 1.5 %}-half-o{% elif review.rating < 2 %}-o {% endif %}" aria-hidden="true"></i>

    <i class="fa fa-star{% if review.rating == 2.5 %}-half-o{% elif review.rating < 3 %}-o {% endif %}" aria-hidden="true"></i>

    <i class="fa fa-star{% if review.rating == 3.5 %}-half-o{% elif review.rating < 4 %}-o {% endif %}" aria-hidden="true"></i>

    <i class="fa fa-star{% if review.rating == 4.5 %}-half-o{% elif review.rating < 5 %}-o {% endif %}" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</span>
```

Comment: Your issue is still unclear ! What do you really want ? Just display `font awesome` stars with `v5.13` ? Or other things else ?

Comment: Yeah I just want to display `fontawesome` stars with `v5. 13` but with conditions.

Comment: Or what's the best way to display display the stars. In my database, if I have something like **3.5** as the rating value, then in my html page, I should have 3 full stars and the fourth star will be half while the fifth (also the last) should be empty star

Answer (score 1):

**This is a snippet that can be used to display empty, half or full rating stars (max stars i 5) with font awesome v5+ :**

```
<div class="rating-star">
    <span title="{{ review.rating }}/5">
    <!-- By default the star is full else it is empty otherwise it is half -->
        <i class="fa fa-star{% if review.rating < 0.5%}-o{% elif review.rating >= 0.5 and review.rating < 1 %}-half-o{% endif %}" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-star{% if review.rating < 1.5%}-o{% elif review.rating >= 1.5 and review.rating < 2 %}-half-o{% endif %}" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-star{% if review.rating < 2.5%}-o{% elif review.rating >= 2.5 and review.rating < 3 %}-half-o{% endif %}" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-star{% if review.rating < 3.5%}-o{% elif review.rating >= 3.5 and review.rating < 4 %}-half-o{% endif %}" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-star{% if review.rating < 4.5%}-o{% elif review.rating >= 4.5 and review.rating < 5 %}-half-o{% endif %}" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </span>
    <span><strong>( {{ review.rating }}/5 )</strong></span>
</div>
```

*The explaination :*
We have 3 different states of stars :

1. empty -> `fa fa-star-o`
2. half -> `fa fa-star-half-o`
3. full -> `fa fa-star`

This chain of conditions in the `i` class :

```
class="fa fa-star{% if review.rating < 0.5%}-o{% elif review.rating >= 0.5 and review.rating < 1 %}-half-o{% endif %}"
```

means that the star is empty `if` the rating `<` `0.5`,
star is half `if` the rating is `>=0.5` **and** `<` `1`,
star is full otherwise (star is `==1`)

The same logic happens for the others 4 stars left.
**Here we assume that the total stars is 5**

Comment: The stars has a different name in `version 5.x`. It is now called `fas fa-star-half-alt` for the half star. Even the full star has a different name in `v5.x`.

Comment: I use it with font awesome `V5.8.2` and work fine ! You juste have to replace with the corresponding class name...

Comment: Doing it in `v5.13` seems to trickier. Do you know how I can achieve same thing with `v5.13`. Please